# Type annotation for a subclass of Mapping + dataclass

Tags: python, type-hinting

Ultimately, I wanted to extend the `dataclasses.dataclass` and `collections.Mapping` because I wanted to make dataclasses that I can use `**` operator on with some additional functions.

Since `dataclass` is a function, not a class, I couldn't use inheritance.
So I made a new wrapping function

```
from dataclasses import dataclass as original_dataclass, fields
from collections import Mapping
from typing import Any, Generator, Type

def __iter__(self) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    for field in fields(self):
        yield field.name

def __len__(self) -> int:
    return len(fields(self))

def __getitem__(self, item: Any) -> Any:
    return getattr(self, item)

def additional_function(self):
    print("Yes")

def dataclass(cls: Type) -> Type:
    cls.additional_function = additional_function
    cls.__iter__ = __iter__
    cls.__len__ = __len__
    cls.__getitem__ = __getitem__

    # If `cls` has these methods, then it counts as a Mapping in the python world
    for method in ("__contains__", "keys", "items", "values", "get", "__eq__", "__ne__"):
        setattr(cls, method, getattr(Mapping, method))

    return original_dataclass(cls)

@dataclass
class MyNewClass:
    hello: str

# usage

def usecase_function(hello:str):
    pass

new_class = MyNewClass("hi")
usecase_function(**new_class) # <- vs-code complains here
new_class.hello # <- vs-code complains here
```

The python interpreter(3.8.13) does not throw an error. However, my editor, vs-code is complaining that this is not a Mapping. I assume because I return a mere `Type` as the return of the new `dataclass` function.

So I annotate the return as `Type[Mapping]`. Now, vs-code complains that `new_class` doesn't have the attribute `hello`. I assume because `dataclass` returns a `Type[Mapping]` which doesn't have a `hello` attribute.

But I don't know how to annotate the function `dataclass` in this situation. Does anyone know how to annotate in this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: "The python interpreter(3.8.13) does not throw an error." - it throws errors. You've got typos, missing imports, and even if you fix those, your decorator just [doesn't work](https://ideone.com/JSgSKV).

Comment: @user2357112 Editted.

Comment: I think https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1794 this page would help. Might be problem of type checker rather than python itself.

Comment: Seems like yet another use case for the missing [`Intersection`](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) type.